# display the addition and total of 2 randomly generated integers

Tags: python

im using the random.randint function to generate 2 dice numbers between 1,10

Im trying to dislay the values as so
   for example
   6 + 7 = 13
but all I can display is the sum of both

my code is

```
dice1 = random.randint(1,10)
dice2 = random.randint(1,10)
print("Player's hand is:", dice1 dice2)
```

Comment: your question is not clear...do you want to display sum of two numbers? i.e. in this case do you want to display 13?  (i.e. 6+7)?

Comment: yes that's correct but I want to display, "6+7=13"

Comment: so just do print "%d+%d=%d"%(dice1, dice2, dice1+dice2)

Comment: @richacam14 do you not see my answer?

Comment: Or the linked duplicate?

Comment: sorry mate @idjaw on my phone, thanks also

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Player's hand is: {} + {} = {}".format(dice1, dice2, dice1 + dice2))
```